# How to reproduce "ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction" in Java readonly transaction

Tags: java, oracle, transactions

I have following java code to set up an oracle connection:

```
private static Connection createConnection() throws SQLException, PublishException { 
  DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver()); 
  String url = PublishingProperties.getDBConnString(); 
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,PublishingProperties.getDBUser(),PublishingProperties.getDBPassword()); 
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
  stmt.exec("alter session set currenct_schema=abc"); 
  conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE); 
  conn.setAutoCommit(false); 
  conn.setReadOnly(true); 
  return conn; 
}
```

With above connection defined, my code would select some views/tables from an oracle db and dump the view/table into a xml file. Please note that the transaction is set to read-only. However I get ora-08177 exception all the time if I run the java code. I tried to update related tables while above program is running but cannot reproduce the same error. I basically don't know what caused the exception since my transaction is read-only. Please help out.

Comment: "Please note that the transaction is set to read-only" - read isolation is by default. What you set is a hint to oracle driver to enable some optimizations. If you get 08177 error, probably your current transaction waits to access resource while another transaction locked it (makes "for update"), when the latter commits it, the first one fails

Comment: Thank you for the response. 
My understanding is:
1.since this is a development database, no other sessions would lock the same record that my read-only session is trying to access. 
2.even though other sessions might lock the same record, this should not affect my read-only transaction, should it?